# Need to manipulate my url

Tags: php, model-view-controller, .htaccess, url-rewriting, codeigniter-2

I'm literally just starting to throw a site together today, so I don't even have much to work with yet, but I wanted to throw this out there so I'll have the information when I get there.  I'm using WAMP (not sure which version, but downloaded within the last 6 months) and CodeIgniter 2.0.3.  How do you manipulate the URL to do the following:

```
www.mysite.com/forums ==> forums.mysite.com
www.mysite.com/pc ==> pc.mysite.com
...
```

Would this be something that gets done with the htaccess file or some other way?  And if it is the htaccess file, can someone provide specifics?  I've looked into some sites that try to explain the htaccess file and they just confuse the crap out of me.  :)  lol.  Oh yeah, and how will that look while looking at it on my local host?  Currently my url looks like:

```
localhost/nothingbutcards/
```

Thank you all very much, hope you're enjoying your weekend.

Comment: See the examples in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html or http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/

Comment: It might help to configure your localhost to use namebased vhosts. On Windows you could use your Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts file to configure a "DNS" system... Have a look at the file - it is self explaining. For instance you write:

127.0.0.1 myproject.dev

And than, I am sure WAMP is doing something like that, you check your configs of the Apache server and look for a specific vhosts config, usually called http-vhosts.conf. If so, you need to "activate" it in your httpd.conf. You will than simply create name based vhosts for your project. You need to do this with every project.

Comment: @mario - wow, that's a lot of reading.  That's going to take me some time.  Richard - I'm familiar with etc/hosts, but I'll have to look into the other ones.  However, one question I do have about etc/hosts, how can I do the equivalent of 127.0.0.1/nothingbutcards =>forums.nothingbutcards.com.  When I did that (without the =>) it gave me an error.  So I'm guessing I can't append folder names in there, or just don't know how.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the reference material provided, the below should be a good starting point. It's an HTACCESS approach.

http://terriswallow.com/weblog/2008/htaccess-redirect-a-directory-to-a-subdomain-and-force-www/

I also wanted to mention, some web hosts now have this as an option in the configuration panel. Mine does, so I can go in, specify a subdomain and the path on the site it points to, and I'm done.